# Duplicate records in hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm getting some records from multiple tables. With Hibernate `join fetch` query.
But I'm getting duplicate records. If I specify `setMaxResults` parameter without any modification the query its working fine. I don't know what is wrong with the query.

Table structure is `products` to `Quantity` (one to many) and `products` to `category`(many to one) and `products` to `brand`(many to one)

My query looks like:

```
from ProductVO  p 
join fetch p.productsWithQuantity pq 
join fetch pq.store 
join fetch p.category cat 
join fetch p.brand brand 
join fetch p.subCategorys subCategory 
where  pq.productId=p.productId
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of join between product and quantity table, because quantity table has multiple rows for a product. Try to use DISTINCT.